# PyQt5: Program crashes after a certain number of push buttons is added into a GridLayout

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am making a grid of push buttons. I realized that if I create a grid with rows > 80 and cols > 90, then my program crashes. What I mean by "crashes" is that the program window opens for one second, then closes again. What's even stranger is that I don't get any error messages in my command prompt.

Does anyone know why this may be happening?

```
self.midColLayout = QVBoxLayout()
self.graphWidget = QWidget(self)
self.graphWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; padding:0px;")
self.graphWidget.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Ignored, QSizePolicy.Ignored)

self.vLayout = QVBoxLayout()
self.hLayout = QHBoxLayout()

self.gridLayout = QGridLayout()
self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0) 
self.hLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout)
self.vLayout.addLayout(self.hLayout)

self.buttons = []
for x in range(0, 80): # If I put 81, then the program crashes
    l = []
    for y in range(0, 90): # If I put 91, then the program crashes
        self.button = QPushButton()
        l.append(self.button)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button, x, y)
    self.buttons.append(l)

self.graphWidget.setLayout(self.vLayout)
self.midColLayout.addWidget(self.graphWidget)
```

Comment: change `self.graphWidget = QWidget()` to `self.graphWidget = QWidget(self)`

Comment: @S.Nick I added "self" but the error still exists

Comment: You need to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which includes all imports and other lines of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.midColLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.graphWidget = QWidget(self)                                         ## self
        self.graphWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; padding:0px;")
        self.graphWidget.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Ignored, QSizePolicy.Ignored)

        self.vLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.hLayout = QHBoxLayout()

        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0) 
        self.hLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout)
        self.vLayout.addLayout(self.hLayout)

        self.buttons = []
        for x in range(0, 80): # If I put 81, then the program crashes
            l = []
            for y in range(0, 90): # If I put 91, then the program crashes
                self.button = QPushButton()
                l.append(self.button)
                self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button, x, y)
            self.buttons.append(l)

        self.graphWidget.setLayout(self.vLayout)
#?        self.midColLayout.addWidget(self.mapLabel)
        self.midColLayout.addWidget(self.graphWidget)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myapp = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mywin = Widget()
    mywin.resize(400, 400)
    mywin.show()
    sys.exit(myapp.exec_())
```

[image]

---

> The code works! I noticed that the grid goes outside of the window. Is there a quick fix for that?

Try it

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.midColLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.graphWidget = QWidget(self)                                          ## self
        self.graphWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; padding:0px;")
        self.graphWidget.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Ignored, QSizePolicy.Ignored)

        self.vLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)                                          # +++ self
        self.hLayout = QHBoxLayout()

        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0) 
        self.hLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout)
        self.vLayout.addLayout(self.hLayout)

        self.buttons = []
        for x in range(0, 80): # If I put 81, then the program crashes
            l = []
            for y in range(0, 90): # If I put 91, then the program crashes
                self.button = QPushButton()
                l.append(self.button)
                self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button, x, y)
            self.buttons.append(l)

#        self.graphWidget.setLayout(self.vLayout)                                   # ---
#?        self.midColLayout.addWidget(self.mapLabel)
        self.midColLayout.addWidget(self.graphWidget)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myapp = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mywin = Widget()
    mywin.resize(400, 400)
    mywin.show()
    sys.exit(myapp.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: The code works! I noticed that the grid goes outside of the window. Is there a quick fix for that?

Comment: With the new update, the original behavior happens. If I make the grid size bigger than 80x90 then the program breaks.

Comment: I am making a color map like the one in this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61877376/pyqt5-how-to-make-a-clickable-color-map-using-qpainter).

I can't use matplotlib because my program will be distributed to computers that don't have the library pre-installed. That's why I am trying to make a grid using buttons. However, I noticed that buttons really slow down my program. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @burntchowmein   see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59521183/draw-a-correct-grid-with-pyqt5